# jQuery - Autocomplete - keystroke errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I added autocomplete functionality to a textbox in my application -

```
    $( "#cplPageContent_ctlInputSrch_txtSearch" ).autocomplete({
        source: aAvailableTags
    });
```

aAvailableTags is a comma delimited list.

I included - 
    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
and http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js.

Every time I type something into this text box, I get a JScript runtime error - 
    'PAGE UP' is null or not an object.  -or-
    'PAGE DOWN' is null or not an object.

There is a series of about 6-8 errors. What would cause those errors?

Comment: Can you post your aAvailableTags variable?

Comment: aAvailableTags = namelast,namefirst,email

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ It needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#cplPageContent_ctlInputSrch_txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: $.makeArray(aAvailableTags)
});
```

Comment: All these options make sense. I tried each one and I still get the same error. It's like there is something wrong with one of the js libraries I am including. Could that be possible?

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on.  Try putting just the autocomplete with its source in a jsFiddle and remove all the other variables.

Comment: Yea, that works. The text box seems to load the autocomplete options correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `source` is an array.

So:

```
aAvailableTags = ['namelast', 'namefirst', 'email'];
```

or

```
aAvailableTags = [namelast, namefirst, email];
```

if `namelast`, `namefirst`, `email` are already defined.

**[Here](http://jsbin.com/apejal/edit#javascript,html,live)** is working code.

Comment: So in my code about, can I just change source to - source: aAvailableTags.split(',')  ?

Comment: @duckmite If `aAvailableTags` is a string containing comma-separated values, then yes, exactly :).